# Dependencies issues linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic

Tags: apt, kernel, updates, dpkg

Was setting up Postfix but didn't get too far, because Ubuntu returned an dependencies error.
Tried to fix this but I cant find the cause to the problem.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic: 
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic depends on
linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic; however:   Package
linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic
(--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
dependency problems prevent configuration of
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic: 
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic depends on
linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic; however:   Package
linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic
(--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured dpkg:
dependency problems prevent configuration of
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-41-generic: 
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-41-generic depends on
linux-image-3.13.0-41-generic; however:   Package
linux-image-3.13.0-41-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-41-generic
(--configure):  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were
encountered while processing:  linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic 
linux-image-3.13.0-41-generic  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic 
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic 
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-41-generic root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get
install -f Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The
following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
required:   linux-headers-3.13.0-32 linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-33 linux-headers-3.13.0-33-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-34 linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-35 linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-36 linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-37 linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-40 linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic  
linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic  
linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic  
linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic  
linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-33-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove
them. The following extra packages will be installed:  
linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic Suggested packages:   fdutils
linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools The following NEW
packages will be installed   linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic 0 to
upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 82 not to upgrade. 5 not
fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/15.1 MB of archives. After
this operation, 42.1 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you
want to continue? [Y/n] y (Reading database ... 358605 files and
directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
.../linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic_3.13.0-43.72_amd64.deb ... Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic (3.13.0-43.72) ... dpkg: error
processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic_3.13.0-43.72_amd64.deb
(--unpa                         ck):  cannot copy extracted data for
'./boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic' to
'/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic.dpkg-new': f                        
ailed to write (No space left on device) No apport report written
because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was                          killed
by signal (Broken pipe) Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d . run-parts:
executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-43-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic run-parts: executing
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-43-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic The link /initrd.img is a damaged link
Removing symbolic link initrd.img  you may need to re-run your boot
loader[grub] The link /initrd.img.old is a damaged link Removing
symbolic link initrd.img.old  you may need to re-run your boot
loader[grub] Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic_3.13.0-43.72_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) root@ubuntu:~#
sudo apt-get autoremove Reading package lists... Done Building
dependency tree Reading state information... Done You might want to
run ‘apt-get -f install’ to correct these. The following packages have
unmet dependencies.  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic : Depends:
linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic but it is not installed E: Unmet
dependencies. Try using -f. root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get install
postfix Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading
state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f install'
to correct these: The following packages have unmet dependencies. 
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic : Depends:
linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed E:
Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or
specify a solution). root@ubuntu:~# clear root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get
install postfix Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done You might want to run 'apt-get -f
install' to correct these: The following packages have unmet
dependencies.  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic : Depends:
linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic but it is not going to be installed E:
Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or
specify a solution). root@ubuntu:~# sudo apt-get -f install Reading
package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state
information... Done Correcting dependencies... Done The following
packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:  
linux-headers-3.13.0-32 linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-33 linux-headers-3.13.0-33-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-34 linux-headers-3.13.0-34-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-35 linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-36 linux-headers-3.13.0-36-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-37 linux-headers-3.13.0-37-generic  
linux-headers-3.13.0-40 linux-headers-3.13.0-40-generic  
linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic linux-image-3.13.0-33-generic  
linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic linux-image-3.13.0-35-generic  
linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic linux-image-3.13.0-37-generic  
linux-image-3.13.0-40-generic linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-33-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-35-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-37-generic  
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-40-generic
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-43-generic Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove
them. The following extra packages will be installed:  
linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic Suggested packages:   fdutils
linux-doc-3.13.0 linux-source-3.13.0 linux-tools The following NEW
packages will be installed   linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic 0 to
upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 82 not to upgrade. 5 not
fully installed or removed. Need to get 0 B/15.1 MB of archives. After
this operation, 42.1 MB of additional disk space will be used. Do you
want to continue? [Y/n] y (Reading database ... 358605 files and
directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack
.../linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic_3.13.0-43.72_amd64.deb ... Done.
Unpacking linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic (3.13.0-43.72) ... dpkg: error
processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic_3.13.0-43.72_amd64.deb
(--unpack):  cannot copy extracted data for
'./boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic' to
'/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space
left on device) No apport report written because the error message
indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d . run-parts: executing
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-43-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic run-parts: executing
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-43-generic
/boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-43-generic Errors were encountered while
processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.13.0-43-generic_3.13.0-43.72_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) root@ubuntu:~#
```

Any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is full.  `failed to write (No space left on device) No apport report written
because the error message indicates a disk full error`

Download the [gparted live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) and extend your system partition first! (resize another partition to make space for it.)

Then do a `sudo apt-get autoremove` then continue as before.

(If you add the output of `sudo parted --list` *to your question* I can give you a more detailed answer.)

Comment: And as you're a reputation 16 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as your and my reputation will go up...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/TmSf3sS.png Infomation from parted --list

Comment: You're using LVM.  Haven't tried that yet, so cannot help you further...  If you want me to delete my answer, drop me a note as questions without answers attract more "hunters for unsolved questions" (like me)

Comment: Cleared out my owncloud and set free space, it works somewhat, so ill call this a short term solution.

Comment: So?  A little click on ☑ would make me happy @tzk_nor  **;-)**